# WordPress file data not sent to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I was wondering if anyone could point out why the file data is not been sent to my database?
The file is sent to a seperate folder but the file information isn't been sent to my database.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'sollicitatie_formulier' ) ) {
        function sollicitatie_formulier(){
            global $wpdb;
            if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
            { 
            $table = tbl_uploads;
            $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
            $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
            $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
            $folder="wp-content/themes/jobify-extended/uploads/";
            $data = array(
                'voornaam' => $_POST['avoornaam'],
                'familienaam' => $_POST['afamilienaam'],
                'comment' => $_POST['amsg'],

            );
            // new file size in KB
            $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
            // new file size in KB

            // make file name in lower case
            $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
            // make file name in lower case

            $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
            $format = array(
                '%s',
                '%s'
            );

            if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file)) 
            {
                $success=$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format, $final_file, $file_type, $new_size );
                if($success){
                ?>
                    <script>
                    alert('successfully uploaded');
                    window.location.href='sollicitatie-formulier?success';
                    </script>
    <?php

}
}
}
```

Comment: **Please note:** You may still run into file name collisions with this code, I would be sure to do some checking if the file exists or use a timestamp in your file name to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the number of elements in $data should match the number of elements in $format.

Also the parameters after $format, which are: $final_file, $file_type, $new_size are not mentioned in the documentation for the insert function.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Examples_5